# Wait Handles and the System.Threading.Tasks namespace

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

When I use `Parallel.ForEach` or `Parallel.For` in the `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace, can I assume that all threads are synchronised before execution continues?

Is there something equivalent to

```
WaitHandle.WaitAll(...);
```

going on?

So If I call something like

```
Parallel.ForEach(collection, DoSomethingWithObject);
```

Can I be certain that each call to `DoSomethingWithObject` has completed *before* `ForEach` returns, or do I need to use `WaitHandles` myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the tasks will have completed by the time `Parallel.ForEach()` returns, unless a call to `Stop()` was specifically made to abort the parallel execution. In such cases, the `.IsCompleted` property of the `ParallelLoopState` object returned by `Parallel.ForEach()` will be `false`.

You can read about it here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopresult.aspx

You can also write a small test application where `DoSomethingWithObject()` is a very long running operation, or a call to `Thread.Sleep()`, to verify this. Execution will block until all threads have finished sleeping.

Sample:

```
Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(1, 8),
    i =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine(i + " done!");
    });
Console.WriteLine("All done!");
```

Comment: Thanks. I wrote a test where `DoSomethingWithObject` sleeps for 3 seconds. Behaviour was as expected.

Answer (score 3):

To extend on Phong's correct answer, Parallel.For and Parallel.ForEach internally create a so called ParallelXXXReplicationTask which is run synchronously and spawns X number of child tasks where X is the effective amount of concurrency level (default Environment.ProcessorCount). Each child task synchronizes with a Semphore which releases the Parent task once set (count to 0) which ensures that the execution of the parent task will only return once all child tasks have finished (or crashed/stopped which is determined through synchronized settings). Since the parentTask is ran synchronously and is being waited for. You can ensure that whenever your call to a Parallel method returns, all iterations have been finished effectively.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I be certain that each call to DoSomethingWithObject has completed
>   before ForEach returns, or do I need to use WaitHandles myself?

`Parallel.ForEach` is a blocking call. It will not return until every iteration has completed.

> Is there something equivalent to `WaitHandle.WaitAll(...);` going on?

Yes, more or less. It would not actually use `WaitHandle.WaitAll` because 1) it would be horribly inefficient and 2) it is not scalable since it has a 64 handle limit. There are a few very scalable techniques for waiting on multiple tasks to complete. One of my favorites is to use `CountdownEvent`.<sup>1</sup>

Here is how it works. Use your imagination and pretend `Parallel.ForEach` gets expanded into the following code.<sup>2</sup>

```
var finished = new CountdownEvent(1);
foreach (var item in collection)
{
  var capture = item;
  finished.AddCount();
  Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () =>
    {
      try
      {
        DoSomething(capture);
      }
      finally
      {
        finished.Signal();
      }
    });
}
finished.Signal();
finished.Wait();
```

---

<sup>1</sup>I am not saying this is the technique used by `Parallel.ForEach`, but it is probably something similar.

<sup>2</sup>In reality `Parallel.ForEach` is implemented in a much more complex manner. I am only trying to help you visualize how it might wait for each iteration to complete.

Answer (score 0):

`Parallel.ForEach()` and `Parallel.For()` will block until all of its tasks have ended, either because they completed successfully or because they were canceled. So yes, all threads are synchronized before execution continues.